Data not ingesting in Druid from Kafka
I have setup Kafka streaming and connected it to Druid, here is my spec
{
  "type": "index_kafka",
  "id": "index_kafka_fleet_81a0ad81b32486d_ifbnmmdf",
  "resource": {
    "availabilityGroup": "index_kafka_fleet_81a0ad81b32486d",
    "requiredCapacity": 1
  },
  "dataSchema": {
    "dataSource": "fleet",
    "timestampSpec": {
      "column": "ts",
      "format": "posix",
      "missingValue": null
    },
    "dimensionsSpec": {
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "name": "lon",
          "multiValueHandling": "SORTED_ARRAY",
          "createBitmapIndex": true
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "name": "id",
          "multiValueHandling": "SORTED_ARRAY",
          "createBitmapIndex": true
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "name": "lat",
          "multiValueHandling": "SORTED_ARRAY",
          "createBitmapIndex": true
        }
      ],
      "dimensionExclusions": [
        "__time",
        "fuelPercentage",
        "speedKmHr",
        "count",
        "ts"
      ],
      "includeAllDimensions": false,
      "useSchemaDiscovery": false
    },
    "metricsSpec": [
      {
        "type": "count",
        "name": "count"
      },
      {
        "type": "longMin",
        "name": "fuelPercentage",
        "fieldName": "fuelPercentage"
      },
      {
        "type": "longMax",
        "name": "speedKmHr",
        "fieldName": "speedKmHr"
      }
    ],
    "granularitySpec": {
      "type": "uniform",
      "segmentGranularity": "HOUR",
      "queryGranularity": "SECOND",
      "rollup": true,
      "intervals": []
    },
    "transformSpec": {
      "filter": null,
      "transforms": []
    }
  },
  "tuningConfig": {
    "type": "KafkaTuningConfig",
    "appendableIndexSpec": {
      "type": "onheap",
      "preserveExistingMetrics": false
    },
    "maxRowsInMemory": 150000,
    "maxBytesInMemory": 0,
    "skipBytesInMemoryOverheadCheck": false,
    "maxRowsPerSegment": 5000000,
    "maxTotalRows": null,
    "intermediatePersistPeriod": "PT10M",
    "maxPendingPersists": 0,
    "indexSpec": {
      "bitmap": {
        "type": "roaring"
      },
      "dimensionCompression": "lz4",
      "stringDictionaryEncoding": {
        "type": "utf8"
      },
      "metricCompression": "lz4",
      "longEncoding": "longs"
    },
    "indexSpecForIntermediatePersists": {
      "bitmap": {
        "type": "roaring"
      },
      "dimensionCompression": "lz4",
      "stringDictionaryEncoding": {
        "type": "utf8"
      },
      "metricCompression": "lz4",
      "longEncoding": "longs"
    },
    "reportParseExceptions": false,
    "handoffConditionTimeout": 0,
    "resetOffsetAutomatically": false,
    "segmentWriteOutMediumFactory": null,
    "intermediateHandoffPeriod": "P2147483647D",
    "logParseExceptions": false,
    "maxParseExceptions": 2147483647,
    "maxSavedParseExceptions": 0,
    "skipSequenceNumberAvailabilityCheck": false
  },
  "ioConfig": {
    "type": "kafka",
    "taskGroupId": 0,
    "baseSequenceName": "index_kafka_fleet_81a0ad81b32486d",
    "startPartitions": {
      "type": "end",
      "stream": "fleet",
      "topic": "fleet",
      "partitionSequenceNumberMap": {
        "0": 8
      },
      "partitionOffsetMap": {
        "0": 8
      }
    },
    "endPartitions": {
      "type": "end",
      "stream": "fleet",
      "topic": "fleet",
      "partitionSequenceNumberMap": {
        "0": 9223372036854775807
      },
      "partitionOffsetMap": {
        "0": 9223372036854775807
      }
    },
    "startSequenceNumbers": {
      "type": "start",
      "stream": "fleet",
      "topic": "fleet",
      "partitionSequenceNumberMap": {
        "0": 8
      },
      "partitionOffsetMap": {
        "0": 8
      },
      "exclusivePartitions": []
    },
    "endSequenceNumbers": {
      "type": "end",
      "stream": "fleet",
      "topic": "fleet",
      "partitionSequenceNumberMap": {
        "0": 9223372036854775807
      },
      "partitionOffsetMap": {
        "0": 9223372036854775807
      }
    },
    "consumerProperties": {
      "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
    },
    "pollTimeout": 100,
    "useTransaction": true,
    "inputFormat": {
      "type": "kafka",
      "headerFormat": null,
      "keyFormat": null,
      "valueFormat": {
        "type": "json",
        "keepNullColumns": false,
        "assumeNewlineDelimited": false,
        "useJsonNodeReader": false
      },
      "headerColumnPrefix": "kafka.header.",
      "keyColumnName": "kafka.key",
      "timestampColumnName": "ts"
    },
    "configOverrides": null
  },
  "context": {
    "checkpoints": "{\"0\":{\"0\":8}}",
    "useLineageBasedSegmentAllocation": true,
    "IS_INCREMENTAL_HANDOFF_SUPPORTED": true,
    "forceTimeChunkLock": true
  },
  "groupId": "index_kafka_fleet",
  "dataSource": "fleet"
}

All services also seem fine

Also in Load Data I see correct data

But when querying I get below error

Can someone please help where I could be going wrong.
